# How to find a HtmlGenericControl using a Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, class

I'm trying to figure out how to find a "div" which is in my main .aspx page from a class, is this possible? If so how? I've tried the code below but is not working

```
HtmlGenericControl step1 = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("step1")
```

I know this is the way I would do it in the code behind file but in this case I want to do it from a class file.

Thank you in advance.

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is this, I have multiple divs in my page all of the have runtat="server" visible="false" when certain criteria is met I want to be able to change the visible="true". I have this scenario in multiple pages so I want to be able to create a Class and check for the conditions there and through this way make the div visible or un-visible

Comment: It ain't a server control, so highly unlikely that you would be able to find it on the server side, maybe you need to explain what is the problem you intend to solve

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is this, I have multiple divs in my page all of the have runtat="server" visible="false" when certain criteria is met I want to be able to change the visible="true". I have this scenario in multiple pages so I want to be able to create a Class and check for the conditions there and through this way make the div visible or un-visible.

Comment: @Jorame: See my solution, this is exactly what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div element must have the runat="server" attribute:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="step1" runat="server"></div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Now, you can find the control with a method in a separated class, which is called from the code behind class of the page:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    class1.FindDiv(this);
  }
}
```

Separated class:

```
public class Class1
{
  public HtmlGenericControl FindDiv(Page page)
 { 
    HtmlGenericControl step1 = (HtmlGenericControl)page.FindControl("step1");
    return step1;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ASP Panel instead of a div u can access it and Panel renders as div. If u give runat="server" to a div u should be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that if it is  not a server side control..

If it is a HTML control you need to set `runat="server"` attribute to the div to find it in code behind..

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)this.FindControl("div1");
```

Note : In order to make this code work, you need to have runat="server" property at aspx page.